# Interpreting centered binary variable in MLM

Tags: multilevel-analysis, binary-data, centering

I'm using multilevel modeling in a situation where I must center a level 1 binary predictor (coded 0/1), following recommendations made here:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Davood_Tofighi/publication/6274186_Centering_Predictor_Variables_in_Cross-Sectional_Multilevel_Models_A_New_Look_at_an_Old_Issue/links/00b49534958cf98ac5000000.pdf

How should I interpret my coefficients for this variable? It is impossible to have a 1 unit increase above the centered mean, so I think traditional interpretation of binary variables are off the table. Is this right, and if so, how can I increase the interpretability of this coefficient?

Comment: Help!! Anybody!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue with interpreting the intercept of a logistic mixed model with a centered binary and centered continuous predictor.